# store multiple check boxes in mysql from django form

Tags: python, mysql, checkbox, django-forms

I am not able to send the selected checkboxes value to mysql database. Please help me in finding out what i missed in the code. When i try to submit the form, it is just redirecting to the same form without any errors and in the same way it is not storing the values in database.

**views.py**

```py
def personview(request):  
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form =PersonForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST.getlist('choosetopics[]'))
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:
                form.save()


            except:  
                print("not valid")  
    else:  
        form = PersonForm()  

    return render(request,'person_list.html',{'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(CollegeAttributes, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domains, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    choosetopics = models.ForeignKey(domain_topics, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```